# Visual Studio For Mac Not Seeing Simulators

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, visual-studio-mac

I have taken delivery of a new Macbook Pro (M2 Pro) and I'm setting it up for development. I've installed the latest XCode (14.3) and Visual Studio For Mac (17.5.3)

I've opened up a project but I'm not able to see the iOS Simulators to test on. I've re-installed both, ensured that VS is pointing to the SDK (/Applications/Xcode.app) as well as opening up XCode first to ensure all licenses and such like have been accepted. However I'm still not seeing any Simulators. I can see them in Xcode, and can run them and run a Flutter app from Visual Studio Code on a Simulator. I just can't get Visual Studio For Mac to see them.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morning Ian, also seeing this issue since updating to Xcode 14.3. Waiting on Visual Studio for Mac update to add support for Xcode 14.3. You should be able to install Xcode 14.2 from https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode as a short term workaround.

Comment: I could have sworn that  I had downgraded my Xcode, but I tried again and 14.2 seems to work. Very odd.

Comment: An alternative that worked for me is to manually select the 14.2 version of Xcode under Preferences... Build and Debug > SDK Locations > Apple.  Then browse to Applications and you should have your choice of Xcode 14.1, 14.2, and 14.3.

Answer (score 3):

If both your VS Code and XCode are up to date andd you are getting this error:

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
  Command: xcrun xcodebuild -list -project Runner.xcodeproj
```

Goto:
**Xcode** -> **Preferences/Settings** -> **Locations**

Select **Command Line Tools** from the drop-down menu. If there is only one version of Xcode installed, there should only be one option. If there are multiple Xcode versions, you must select the one you want.

If the dropdown shows an already version, make sure to reselect it. You should be prompted for authorization.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you can download and install [this package](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/60490eec-956e-47b3-b063-79cadfe6ef11/b9c977eb4bc99a72f1deed54a680bd67/xamarin.ios-16.4.0.3.pkg).
Source https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-09-27 now waiting for Visual Studio for Mac to be updated to support XCode 15. I have an XCode 14.3.1 install also on my Mac and can swap to that with `xcode-select` then I see simulators.

With XCode 15 as my selected IDE, I get the frustrating typical message:

*Lower the 'Deployment Target' to see older simulators or check your Apple SDK path"* which translates as

*I don't understand the current XCode*.

XCode15 compatibility is still an open issue [17837](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17837) on the iOS/macIOS Xamarin repo.

Comment: If it gets updated to support XCode 15. Given the impending demise of Visual Studio for Mac, I'm not convinced MS will bother to update to support it.